# $n$ families with $k$ members and $r$ rooms

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we have $nk$ persons such that there are $n$ families with $k$ members. We have $r$ rooms and we want to send persons to rooms such that each room has exactly one person. I want to count all possible cases. But we have a condition.
I explain with an example:

Assume that a person of first family went to first room. We cannot send other person of his family to other rooms. So we should choose a person of other families.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly then if $r \gt n$ there is no possible arrangement. otherwise there are $\binom{n}{r}$ ways of selecting $r$ families, $k^r$ ways of selecting a single member from each chosen family, and then $r!$ ways of arranging these chosen individuals into $r$ rooms. altogether this gives:

$$
\frac{n!k^r}{(n-r)!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

So basically each room has exactly one person, and each family can send at most only one person. So this is possible only if number of families is greater than number of rooms, because otherwise few rooms would remain empty, (assuming that is not allowed).

So select r persons for r rooms, and hence r families, because 1 family sends 1 person--(nCr).

Now each family can send any 1 of their k members, so (kC1), r families, so (kC1)^r.

And assuming rooms are distinct, they can be arranged in r! ways.

Hence No. of ways will be **(nCr)*(kC1)^r*r!**.

NOTE:- Assumption of number of families greater  than no. of rooms might not be necessarily true, but now you got the idea, and can do it yourself.